# Black Lines After pressing smooth

Tags: modeling

I have this Problem in Blender.
After Pressing the smooth button in object mode, it creates a black line, which i think is shadow, around my object.

[image]

Link to image: (If above image doesn't display)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMjx8.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Feel free to upvote the original question. And if you find a helpful answer, that too. :-)